# Autocomplete/search suggestions with Material Design Lite?

Tags: html, css, autocomplete, autosuggest, material-design-lite

so there's no built-in mechanism in `material-design-lite` v1.x for "chips" or lists to be attached to an input/search field, and/or be populated/displayed in response to an event.

I found this: http://immybox.js.org/ — but is there a best practice in general for MDL, with autocomplete/search suggest?

---

Or, something like **Google/YouTube** search bar in MDL?

[image: Google app search bar Android]

Answer (score 3):

There is a thread on this here:
[Component Request Autocomplete · Issue #877 · google/material ...](https://github.com/google/material-design-lite/issues/877)

To answer your question

> is there a best practice in general for MDL, with autocomplete/search suggest?

It is according to that, officially unresolved. Which is annoying because it would be really great, especially with chip integration like a cross between these two:

Angular Material Autocomplete & Angular Material Chips

[Angular Material](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/autocomplete)